# ProtocolBuffer missing required fields but they are filled in

Tags: c++, multithreading, protocol-buffers, winsock

I'm creating a client-server environment and I have just implemented UDP. I was only working and testing with a TCP connection before and then everything worked fine.
Now, if I try to send packets to the server from the client I get an error that some required fields weren't filled in which they cleary are (see code later on). I don't really have an idea why this is happening since it worked before.

One thing I guess that can be important, the receive method of the TCP socket and the UDP socket are on a different thread. (the server uses multithreading)

So, Here's some code:

The TCP Receive (part of it):

```
iResult = recv(m_Connections[t].socket, m_TCPRecvbuf, m_TCPRecvbuflen, 0);

// Deserialize the data
MessageID* receivedData = new MessageID();
receivedData->ParseFromArray((char*)m_TCPRecvbuf, receivedData->packetsize());
```

I did the size in ParseFromArray with iResult at first (which seemed to work) but I changed it so I put the size in the data itself. (which has now become receivedData->packetsize())

The UDP Receive (part of it) on a different thread:

```
iResult = recvfrom(m_UDPListenSocket, m_UDPRecvbuf, m_UDPRecvbuflen, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&address, &addrlen);
// Deserialize the data
MessageID* receivedData = new MessageID();
receivedData->ParseFromArray((char*)m_TCPRecvbuf, receivedData->packetsize());
```

This is the first creation of a packet that gets sent:

```
void NetworkInterface::SendLoginData(string username, string password)
{
// Create base message
// -----------------
MessageID message;
message.set_type(MessageID::Type::MessageID_Type_LOGINDATA);

// Create logindata
// ------------------
LoginData data = message.logindata();
data.set_username(username);
data.set_password(password);

// Create packet
// ----------------------
int size = message.ByteSize();
void* buffer = malloc(size);

message.set_packetsize(size);
message.set_clientid(0);

message.SerializeToArray(buffer, size);

if (m_pTCPNetworkingObject != nullptr)
    m_pTCPNetworkingObject->SendData(buffer, size);
else
    printf("NetworkInterface [ERROR]: No connection data was found. Please use CreateConnectionObject() first!\n");
}
```

The error that it gives after this is that the Type, ClientID and packetSize fields are missing but you can see those are filled in

Here's the SendData() method:

```
void SendData(void* data, int size)
{
    // SEND DATA
    int iResult;
    iResult = send(m_TCPConnectSocket, (char*)data, size, 0 );
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) 
        printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
}
```

This is about all the information I can give. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're calling `receivedData->packetsize()` on a new message - is that deliberate? Shouldn't you be using `iResult`? Are you certain that a whole message can be transmitted in a single UDP packet?

Comment: Where are you getting the error exactly? Is it a compilation error or during runtime?

Comment: @JonSkeet that is true. I haven't checked that for UDP. Hmm yeah, the packetsize thing... I should check that as well then
o_weisman It is at runtime

Comment: @Dries: What do you mean by "the first part of the packet is read first"? Have you debugged what the call to `packetsize()` returns?

Comment: Yeah, I was wrong... This can't work. I'm using iResult now but it still gives me the same error. I'm trying over TCP now btw

Comment: [Here's](http://pastebin.com/wWyBFakr) my .proto file by the way. The one that defines the packet I send

Comment: I don't think you ever set the loginData fields in the message did you? You create a LoginData but you don't transfer ownership to the Message Neither do you store the LoginData in the buffer before calling `send()`.

Comment: Hmm... I'll check it but it should be this line: `LoginData data = message.logindata();`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems:

1) deserialization:

```
receivedData->ParseFromArray((char*)m_TCPRecvbuf, receivedData->packetsize());
```

You call `packetSize` before it gets filled by `parseFromArray`, use `iResult` instead.

2) LoginData:

```
LoginData data = message.logindata();
```

This reads a copy of messages empty loginData, you never change `message`. Use

```
LoginData* data = message.mutable_logindata();
```

to get a pointer to messages loginData an modify it within `message`.

3) serialization:

```
int size = message.ByteSize();
void* buffer = malloc(size);
```

this uses the size of an empty message (since loginData is not set). So you never send the full message.
You have to call `ByteSize()` after all properties are set. This contradicts with the packetSize within your message.
Since you can't use it for deserialization anyway (see 1) you should remove this entry.